# bootstrap modal is on button click but it is lying hidden in the background on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a bootstrap modal which was wroking fine on one of my projects, when I used that modal in another project I dont know why it is lying hidden in the background and doesnt allow to overlap any other modal to open. I can see that modal is hidden in background when I move cursor around that area. Please help me fix the problem.
Here is my Default.aspx page:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Template/Main.Master" CodeBehind="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Library.Default2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css"/>
      <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/JavaScript1.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="~/css/StyleSheet1.css" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="float: left; padding-left: 50px">
        <div class="search">
            <asp:textbox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-8" maxlength="64" placeholder="book title"></asp:textbox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" Text="Search" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAllBooks" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" Text="All Books" />

</div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAllBooks" EventName="Click" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptBookList" runat="server" ItemType="Library.GetBooks">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                    <th>Book Title</th>
                                    <th>Author</th>
                                    <th>Genre</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnBookAdd" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Add To Cart"></asp:Button>
                            </td>
                            <td><%# Item.Title() %></td>
                            <td><%# item.Author() %></td>
                            <td><%# Item.Genre() %></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 225px">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnCheckout" runat="server" Text="Checkout" href="#Checkout" font-size="Medium" Font-Underline="true"></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnReturn" runat="server" Text="Return" href="#Return" font-size="Medium" Font-Underline="true" ForeColor="Black"></asp:LinkButton>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnFine" runat="server" Text="Fine" href="#Fine" font-size="Medium" Font-Underline="true" ForeColor="Black"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <div>
                    <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnFamilyAdd" runat="server" text="Add Another User" font-size="Medium" OnClientClick="showModalNewUser()"></asp:Button>
        </div>
    <div>
        <asp:linkbutton ID="lnkbtnGetInfo" runat="server" Text="Get Information" href="#GetInfo" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:linkbutton>
        </div>
    <div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnGetAllmembers" runat="server" Text="List of Family Members" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal.addNewUser -->
    <div id="addAnotherUserModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="lblAddAnotherUserModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">          
           <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h2>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAddAnotherUser" runat="server" CssClass="modal-title">Add Another User</asp:Label>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFamilyAdd" />
                            </Triggers>
                                      <ContentTemplate>
                                           <div>
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblnewFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtnewFirstName" class="form-control" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtnewFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                           <div>
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblnewLastName" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtnewLastName" class="form-control" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtnewLastName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Last Name"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                          <div>
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblnewAddress" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtnewAddress" class="form-control" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtnewAddress" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Address"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                          <div>
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblnewDOB" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12"  class="form-control" Text="Date Of Birth" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                              <div class="row">
                                            <!-- Include Bootstrap Datepicker -->
                                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" />
                                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.min.css" />
                                            <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

                                        <div>
                                         <div class="col-xs-12 date">
                                         <div class="input-group input-append date" id="datePicker">
                                         <input id="dpnewDOB" runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" name="date" />
                                           <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                             </div>
                                          <script>
                                             $(document).ready(function() {
                                             $('#datePicker')
                                             .datepicker({
                                             format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
                                               })
                                           .on('changeDate', function(e) {
                                           // Revalidate the date field
                                          $('#eventForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
                                            });

                                          $('#eventForm').formValidation({
                                           framework: 'bootstrap',
                                         icon: {
                                          valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                                          invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                                          validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                                                    },
                                        fields: {
                                             name: {
                                             validators: {
                                             notEmpty: {
                                            message: 'The name is required'
                                             }
                                             }
                                           },
                                       date: {
                                           validators: {
                                           notEmpty: {
                                          message: 'The date is required'
                                                },
                                            date: {
                                        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                                        message: 'The date is not a valid'
                                             }
                                           }
                                        }
                                      }
                                   });
                                  });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                          <div>
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblnewEmail" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtnewEmail" class="form-control" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtnewEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                          <div>
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblnewPhoneNumber" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtnewPhoneNumber" class="form-control" Text="Phone Number"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtnewPhoneNumber" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Primary Phone Number"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                          <div>
                                              <asp:Label ID="lblnewSecondaryNumber" runat="server" CssClass="col-xs-12" AssociatedControlID="txtnewSecondaryNumber" class="form-control" Text="Secondary Phone Number"></asp:Label>
                                              <asp:TextBox ID="txtnewSecondaryNumber" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Secondary Phone Number"></asp:TextBox>
                                          </div>
                                      </ContentTemplate>
                                  </asp:UpdatePanel>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpnewUser" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnModalnewClose" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" Text="Close" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewUserSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text ="Save" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>

               </div>
        </div>
    </div>


   </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBottomDiv" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showModaladdAnotherUser() {
            $('#addAnotherUserModal').modal();
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.vb:

```
Public Class Default2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        txtSearch.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btnAllBooks_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAllBooks.Click
    InitiateGetAllbooks()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSearch_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    InitiateSearch()
End Sub
Protected Sub btnAddNewUsersave_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddNewUserSave.Click
    InitiateAddNewUser()
   InitiateAddNewUserInfo()
End Sub
Protected Sub lnkbtnGetAllmembers_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkbtnGetAllmembers.Click
    InitiateGetAllFamily()
End Sub
Protected Sub InitiateGetAllBooks()
    Try
        Dim conn As New Connection(Connection.EConnectionString.Library)
        Using conn.Connection
            rptBookList.DataSource = GetBooks.GetAllBooks(conn.Connection)
            rptBookList.DataBind()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Library.Helper.ShowMessage(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Protected Sub InitiateAddNewUser()
    Try
        Dim conn As New Connection(Connection.EConnectionString.Library)
        Using conn.Connection
            Actions.AddUser(txtnewFirstName.Text, txtnewLastName.Text, "10", "1", conn.Connection)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Library.Helper.ShowMessage(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub InitiateAddNewUserInfo()
    Try
        Dim conn As New Connection(Connection.EConnectionString.Library)
        Using conn.Connection
            Actions.addNewUserInformation(txtnewAddress.Text, dpnewDOB.ToString, txtnewEmail.Text, txtnewPhoneNumber.Text, txtnewSecondaryNumber.Text, "100", "1", conn.Connection)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Library.Helper.ShowMessage(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

[image: Here is the image of how modal is running in the background]

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a z-index issue going on.  The z-index controls the layers of different DOM objects.  The highest z-index gets placed on top.  You can add the following CSS which should cause the modal to always appear on top (assuming a z-index of 10000 is high enough):

```
.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```

or

```
.modal.fade {
  z-index: 10000 !important;
}
```